# Push-pull converter: ferrite core transformer dropping voltage

Tags: transformer, dc-dc-converter, ferrite

[image][image: I have provided the schematic, I measured 4.2 volts at the "current in" terminal as well as on the input to the voltage regulator]I am creating a 100 W, 12 V to 120 VAC @50hz inverter. I have implemented a push-pull converter to obtain a 200 VDC link for the H-bridge of the inverter.

I am having problems with the push-pull converter. I wound a ETD39/20/13 (0.5 mm gap) ferrite core 3+3 primary and 65 secondary. I use a [TL494](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tl494) to drive the push-pull MOSFETs.

The problem I have is that when I connect the center tap to the supply I essentially get a short circuit and all the voltages around the circuit are pulled down (to 2-4 V). I've checked the switching signals multiple times and they are as expected, switching at 25 kHz.

Update:
I have change my design for the transformer.

I have used a EE 42/21/15 core with 8+8 turns primary with center tap and 140 turns secondary. I am using the TL494 with voltage feedback switching at 50 kHz (essentially 25 kHz due to push-pull setup).

The same problem arises when I connect the center tap of the transformer, the voltage at the input to the circuit drops to around 4 V and the current into the center tap is measured at 2.2 A. When I measure the secondary side I see a voltage which starts at around 17 V and gradually increases to 33 V.

I have used a 10 μH, 2 A inductor after the full wave rectifier and a 100 μF, 400 V capacitor. I am using fdpf320n06l MOSFETs for the push-pull. I've used a open collector configuration with 1 kΩ pull-up resistors at C1 and C2 of the TL494N and current limiting resistors on the MOSFET gates.

Any advice or suggestion to solve? I am an engineering student doing this for a final project.

Comment: I would start by showing us the schematic of the circuit that doesn't work, and showing which voltages are "all voltages"

Comment: Why are you using a gapped core for the push-pull converter stage? Show us the design equations you used to design this transformer, switching period, turns, core area, AL etc.

Comment: i have provided the schematic in my initial post. https://tahmidmc.blogspot.com/2012/12/ferrite-transformer-turns-calculation.html this is a link to the guide I used to do the calculations, as well as I used software called excellentTI which gave me nearly the same numbers.

Answer (score 2):

> I wound a ETD39/20/13 (0.5 mm gap) ferrite core 3+3 primary and 65 secondary.

Oh boy!

A gapped ETD39 has an A<sub>L</sub> of ~0.3 uH per turns squared! This means that you'll have a primary inductance of 2.7 uH for 3 turns for each half primary. Now remember the inductor equation:

$$
V_L=L \frac{di_L}{dt}
$$

Assuming dt = 5 us (100 kHz, 0.5 duty-cycle, no dead-time) and V<sub>L</sub> = 12V, the di<sub>L</sub> (current rise) will be ~20 Amps! We know that this is going to get worse as the frequency gets lower, and I'm assuming it is in your application, so the peaks should be really high to get the 12V supply shorted. And it appears to be that there's no primary current control present at controller-side because the controller would possibly stop switching before the supply's protection (if any) kicks in.

An un-gapped ETD39 would have an A<sub>L</sub> of something around 2500~3000 nH per turns squared. So, 3 turns would bring an inductance of ~20 uH which seems to be barely meaningful.

What you should do is,

- to get rid of that gapped core and use an un-gapped one. Remember that you don't have to gap the core unless it's really required.
- to revise your calculations and check the equations you used. You should end up with more primary turns. Because, even though 3 turns for half primary brings a flux swing of less than 0.2T which seems reasonable, the primary inductance would be very low and therefore magnetising currents would be very high. More turns don't kill you as you already have a fairly large window area.

Comment: Thanks much for the feedback, I will source the ungapped core. As for the turns calculations, I used a calculator I found online. Excellent TI. I initially calculated the turns myself and arrived at the values 3+3 to 65 and thus I assumed it to be correct since nearly the same when using the calculator. However as you've pointed out I did not take some important things into consideration. Which formulas do you suggest I used for the calculations with the ungapped core?

Comment: @DarrenMillington well, the first thing is the Faraday equation: \$V=N \ A_e \ \Delta B / \Delta t\$, and the other is \$L = A_L \ N^2\$. Ae and AL can be found in the core's datasheet (Note that ungapped AL is much larger than the gapped). Make sure \$\Delta B\$ stays below 0.2T. And finally, \$V = L \ \Delta i/\Delta t\$. \$\Delta i\$ is the peak current that'll flow through the primary winding. Check if your supply can handle that peak current. You need to study the topics first before jumping into design and construction.

Comment: I got a different core which is not gapped. EE42/12/15. Using the equations you mentioned and the ones I originally used for the #of turns I have made another transformer with 8+8 primary and 152 secondary, I checked the inductance value based on A(L) from the datasheet as well as the current rise and all were Ok. 250uH and 0.12 amps. However, when I connect the transformer the result is exactly the same as before. Could you check the schematic I provided in the original post to see if there are any errors which would lead to this occurring?

Comment: @DarrenMillington It's probably because there's no primary current feedback to the TL494. After the circuit is energised the chip will generate the gate pulses but it can't know when to stop generating pulses. That's why it uses the primary current measurement: Once the primary current hits the peak the pulses will be cut then the regulation network will take over. And also it's useful for power limiting in fault conditions (e.g. output overload or short). **PS:** Your schematic is really unreadable i.e. I can't understand what net goes to which pin of the chip.

Comment: I have added the schematic of the TL494 setup, let me know your thoughts. Also where could I add the current sense feedback resistor? at the mosfet source pin?